# Error in if (...) argument is of length zero. NO Null value

Tags: r

I am evaluating multiples files to a function called "myFunction". The values passed to myFunction receives x, y, z, w, o and t.

myFunction has an if statement that compares the values it receives. And based on these values the conditions are evaluated and if true the body of the if statement executes. The code inside the body of the if statement does not execute because of the error inside the expression.

I have checked similar answers that address the "argument is of length zero" error but it seems that my problem does not apply.

when I print the values when the errors occur:

```
x=0  <- can be between 0 to .99999  

y=.99998 <- can be between 0 to .99999

z=18

w= 16 18 19 20

o=10

t=10 11 12 13


if (x < y & z %in% w | o %in% t){   <- error


some code (does not execute)


}
```

> Error in if (x < y & z %in%  :    argument is of length zero

I tried to understand the issue, so I checked if the expression returns null or not but it returns false:

```
 is.null(x < y & z %in% w | o %in% t)
```

> [1]FALSE

```
NULL == (x < y & z %in% w | o %in% t)
```

> logical(0)

```
TRUE == (x < y & z %in% w | o %in% t)
```

> TRUE

```
class(x)
```

> "numeric"

```
class(y)
```

> "numeric"

so as the rest of vars.

(x < y) check to TRUE

so as the rest of the expressions.

Comment: HI, it would be easier to read if you use code formatting for the code part. What do you get by running separately `x<y`, `z %in% w` and `o %in% t` ?

Comment: The error means that either `x`, `y`, `z`, `w`, `o`, or `t` does not exist or is empty when the `if` condition is evaluated. Inspect the value of these after the error has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your variable declaration.

```
w = 16 18 19 20
t = 10 11 12 13
```

should instead be

```
w = c(16, 18, 19, 20)
t = c(10, 11, 12, 13)
```

The c() creates a vector containing the given values. This will let you use the %in% operator the way you are trying to.